# NPS contribution charges and eNPS

Tags: investing, india, pension, pension-plan

1. What are the benefits of eNPS?
2. How can we avoid (a) POP trail commission & (b) Payment Gateway Charge while making a contribution in NPS Tier-1 account?

3.What is the recommended/generalized % allocation in various NPS Schemes under Active choice? keeping in mind that NPS account is opened at the age of 55.

Answer (score 0):

1. The benefits are you can operate and open account online.

2a. Can't be avoided. You have to always pay it. In case of eNPS, the bank facilitates is the  POP.
2b. If you use netbanking, it's 60 paise; alternatively visit the bank and deposit the money.

3. Is opinion based and not good for this site.

Comment: So in eNPS , POP trail commission would not be charged? And if we deposit money via bank , then payment gateway charge will also not be there?

Comment: You always pay  POP trail comission

Comment: But in eNPS there is no POP so why there will be POP commission?
If we deposit money via bank , then payment gateway charge will also not be there, I mean will there be any other charges then?

Comment: The POP will be the Bank website offering the eNPS

Comment: If we deposit money via bank , then payment gateway charge will also not be there, I mean will there be any other charges then?